# Substiution of text pattern in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to use string substitution for a pattern occurring in my data. My pattern currently looks like this-

```
a&b|c
```

I want to substitute it to something like this-

```
(?=.*a)(?=.*b)|c
```

What is the best way to achieve this in R?

Comment: Try `str1 <-  "a&b|c";
 sub("^([a-z])&([a-z])", "(?=.*\\1)(?=.*\\2)", str1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the letter at the start (`^`) of the string followed by `&` and another letter, capture it as a group (`(...)`) and replace with the backreference along with the pattern we need to add

```
sub("^([a-z])&([a-z])", "(?=.*\\1)(?=.*\\2)", str1)
#[1] "(?=.*a)(?=.*b)|c"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "a&b|c"
```

Comment: This won't work for more complicated examples where the & condition is coming multiple times. For example if `str1='(small&business)|(medium&business)'`, it would only work for the small and business combination. How can we make it work for multiple occurrences of &

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  The pattern was based on the example you showed.  What will be the expected output for the `str` with small & business

Comment: So the output should look like this  "(?=.*small)(?=.*business)|(?=.*medium)(?=.*business)"

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  Also, this example is very different from the `a&b|c` as you have multiple instances

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  Try `library(stringr);paste("(?=.*", str_extract_all(str1, "[a-z]+")[[1]], ")", sep="", collapse="")
#[1] "(?=.*small)(?=.*business)(?=.*medium)(?=.*business)"`

Comment: Yes it is. Apologies for that, I tried using `sub("([a-z]*)&([a-z]*)", "(?=.*\\1)(?=.*\\2)(?=.*\\3)", str1)` to account for multiple occurrences of & but it didn't work

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  I think you need `|` between `paste("(?=.*", str_extract_all(str1, "[a-z]+")[[1]], ")", sep="", collapse="|")`

Comment: Using `paste("(?=.*", str_extract_all(str1, "[a-z]+")[[1]], ")", sep="", collapse="|")` gives output as `[1] "(?=.*small)|(?=.*business)|(?=.*medium)|(?=.*business)|(?=.*large)|(?=.*business)"
`

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  Try `v1 <- str_extract_all(str1, "[a-z|]+")[[1]];i1 <- v1 != "|";

v1[i1] <- paste0("(?=.*", v1[i1], ")");paste(v1, collapse="")#
[1] "(?=.*small)(?=.*business)|(?=.*medium)(?=.*business)"`

Comment: How is the variable `i1` getting defined in the above code snippet?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  I just updated the earlier comment.  I forgot to add it earlier

Comment: This worked, thanks. Was just curious to know if there is a way to try and replicate this with the `sub` function you'd suggested originally. Thanks.